# Is there a tool that would let me test connectivity to various servers over various ports?

Tags: windows-7, networking

Recently I've gotten a lot of new servers set up by our networking team for me to develop/test with.  The problem is the firewall access I have to the servers is inconsistent, so I need to figure out what ports on what servers I have access to.

Is there an existing tool that could do this?

For example:

- Connect to Server A over port 80 and report success/failure
- Connect to Server A over port 3389 and report success/failure
- Connect to Server A over port 1433 and report success/failure

Ideally I could give it a list of servers and ports to check, and it could give me a list of what failed so I can request the ports to be opened.

Answer (score 1):

```
 telnet host port
```

or

```
 nmap host -p portnum
```

or

```
 nmap host -p 1-65535
```

Answer (score 1):

[nmap](http://nmap.org) is the thing you are looking for.

If it is necessary for you to this over Windows, then there is Windows version of the program called [zenmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/). You'll additionally need to install [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) for (advanced) port probing with it.

If Linux, a simple bash script would do or just outputing it to file, depends on how will you do it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I can think of is to create a **.bat** file with a list of [paping](http://code.google.com/p/paping/) commands. (As ping does not support port numbers)

```
paping server1 -p 80 -c 4
paping server1 -p 3389 -c 4  
paping www.google.com -p 80 -c 4
etc.
```

By looking at the results, you can see which servers you have access to at the moment.